# Possible to restore a damaged database's PRIMARY filegroup only?

Tags: sql-server, corruption, restore, filegroups, dbcc-checkdb

I have a database (MyDatabase) with 2 filegroups, `[PRIMARY]` and `[SECONDARY]`.

The `[SECONDARY]` filegroup has 2 datafiles, `[DataFileA]` and `[DataFileB]`.

`[DataFileA]` is damaged (even after `DBCC CHECKDB` process).

I tried to solve it with:

1. `DBCC CHECKDB ([MyDatabase], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)` but it didn't help.
2. Deleted the damaged datafile `[DataFileA]`, with no success.

The `[PRIMARY]` filegroup is ok though.

Can I backup just the `[PRIMARY]` filegroup and restore it (under a new name) and create a new database from this single filegroup?

Comment: Do you have any backups to restore from? If not then data loss may be unavoidable

Comment: No, I don't have any backup (I wish I add). And yes, I know . Thanks !

Comment: The database is in ONLINE state.   The problem is that I can not delete\drop [DataFileA], I am getting an error on the delete process that there are damaged pages .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the database is `ONLINE`, you have two main options:

1. Create a new database with the same schema for `[PRIMARY]` filegroup objects as the old database, and transfer data using any of the tools available (e.g. SSIS, bcp, linked server). Depending on the complexity of the existing schema, constraints, and relationships (e.g. foreign keys) this may be quite time-consuming.
2. Take a [partial backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191539.aspx) of the `[PRIMARY]` filegroup only. Restore this to a new database and files using [piecemeal restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177425.aspx). Finally, [mark the filegroup as defunct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175122.aspx). Be sure [`DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187332.aspx) for `[PRIMARY]` runs cleanly first. You should export the schema and data to a safe place as in option 1 as well. As you know, having tested backups of your valuable data is priority #1 :)